# How to change the contents of a collapsable toolbar depending on which activity it is included in?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

In other words, I want to keep my mobile app is modular as possible with a DRY concept in mind. With a regular `Toolbar` used as a `actionbar`, most people call it via `<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`

I want to do this, but with a "collapsible toolbar". The problem is, is it possible to call it via `<include/>` BUT have the contents that are displayed inside the collapsible toolbar to have a different `layout` and content depending on which activity it is being used.

For example:
In main activity, I want the collapsible toolbar to display 3 `TextViews`. In a profile activity, I want the collapsible toolbar to display 1 `ImageView` and 1 `TextView`.

Is such a thing possible? 1 `CollapsibleToolbar.xml <include/>` in multiple activities but with different contents inside.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: findViewById(R.id.imageview).setVisibility(Visibility.GONE);

Comment: You need to use multiple layouts. That are totally different collapsible toolbars. How should a collapsible toolbar having 3 TextViews know that it should have 1 ImageView and only one TextView in the next activity? As Wukash points out you can set visibility but you should rather create different layouts because it gives you more overview and is easier maintainable

Comment: @speedDeveloper Ok, thank you very much! :) I will take your suggestion of creating multiple collapsible toolbars.